# substring don't get a value when reading from a file

Tags: java, substring, java.util.scanner

I'm new in Java so forgive me if i ask something obvious. I understand that you might have better things to do, but if someone could point me in the right direction i would appriciate it.

I extract 14 substrings but the last 4 strings is always empty.
And I'm not sure how to read the next line that starts with 55401.
Is there a hidden limitation on how any substrings i can extrakt?

The file i look in:

1. 55101BUYX     SELLLX    0022200223210924
2. 55201XQ 000897350210924  PARTNUMERXXX                            ZZ           S000000V            0000000000
3. 55301000000000000000000000000000000000000000000I
4. 554012109240000000000462 2109270000000000000 2109280000000000000 2109290000000000000 2109300000000000000 2110010000000000000
5. 554012110040000000000000 2110050000000000000 2110060000000000000 2110070000000000000 0000000000000000000 0000000000000000000
6. 55701                                                                                                    JP010 ASDFGHJK
7. 55901_output000000200000020000004000000000000020000001

From the code below i get the following, the Strings 6 & 7 doesn't get vales.

1. Ship 210924 | QTY 000000462
2. Ship 210927 | QTY 000000000
3. Ship 210928 | QTY 000000000
4. Ship 210929 | QTY 000000000
5. Ship 210930 | QTY 000000000
6. Ship | QTY
7. Ship | QTY

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Mail\\Desktop\\VDA Reader\\VDA.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    String input = "";
    String shipDate1 = "";
    String qty1 = "";
    String shipDate2 = "";
    String qty2 = "";
    String shipDate3 = "";
    String qty3 = "";
    String shipDate4 = "";
    String qty4 = "";
    String shipDate5 = "";
    String qty5 = "";
    String shipDate6 = "";
    String qty6 = "";
    String shipDate7 = "";
    String qty7 = "";
    String callOffs = "55401";
    //Scan next line if exists
    try {
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String outPut = scan.nextLine();
            if(outPut.startsWith(callOffs)){
                shipDate1 =     outPut.substring(5, 11);
                qty1 =          outPut.substring(15, 24);
                shipDate2 =     outPut.substring(25, 31);
                qty2 =          outPut.substring(35, 44);
                shipDate3 =     outPut.substring(45, 51);
                qty3 =          outPut.substring(55, 64);
                shipDate4 =     outPut.substring(65, 71);
                qty4 =          outPut.substring(75, 84);
                shipDate5 =     outPut.substring(85, 91);
                qty5 =          outPut.substring(95, 104);
                shipDate6 =     outPut.substring(105, 101);
                qty6 =          outPut.substring(115, 124);
            }
            if (outPut.startsWith(callOffs)){
                shipDate7 =     outPut.substring(5, 11);
                qty7 =          outPut.substring(15, 24);

            }
            input = input.concat(outPut + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate1 + " | QTY " + qty1);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate2 + " | QTY " + qty2);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate3 + " | QTY " + qty3);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate4 + " | QTY " + qty4);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate5 + " | QTY " + qty5);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate6 + " | QTY " + qty6);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate7 + " | QTY " + qty7);
```

Comment: Your cod never fills in `shipDate6`, `qty6`, `shipDate7` and `qty7` because on the line `shipDate6 =     outPut.substring(105, 101);` the `substring()` methods throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the end index (101) is less than the start index 105. You never see any traces of this exception because your code helpfully catches all exceptions and ignores them.

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend using a proper data structure, which would make this easier to use and read.
You need class e.g. `ShippingInformation`. This class has two attributes `shippingDate` and `quantity`. This class should also contain a constructor taking in both of these arguments.

```
public class ShippingInformation {
    private String shippingDate;
    private String quantity;

    public ShippingInformation(String shippingDate, String quantity) {
        this.shippingDate = shippingDate;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    
    // Getter and Setter for both of the attributes
}
```

Now you don't need to have 14 Strings, where 7 of them contain the same type of information.
Also using `String::substring` this way, it is really hard to read.

You don't need to check if the same line starts with `55401` twice.

The seventh entry can't be filled, because one line only has six of these numbers. It seems you are trying to fill the seventh with the first date and qty of the second line that starts with `55401`, but you are trying to do all of it on the same line.

Look at the following code. It takes in one line, removes `55401` and splits that line at a whitespace. You now have an array filled with six elements. These can be used to extract the needed information in a loop. The extracted information is saved to a list, so you can later use the extracted information.

With this code you should have 12 outputs at the end.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ShippingInformation> shippings = new ArrayList();
        File file = new File("path");
        String callOffs = "55401";

        try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) { // this loop automatically calls the next line, if there is a next line
                String line = scan.nextLine(); // get the next line
                if (line.startsWith(callOffs)) {
                    line = line.replace(callOffs, ""); // replace the value of callOffs
                    String[] split = line.split(" "); // split your line at a whitespace
                    for (String element : split) { // create a ShippingInformation for every eligible entry
                        shippings.add(new ShippingInformation(element.substring(0, 6), element.substring(10, 19)));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(ShippingsInformation shipping: shippings) {
            System.out.println("Ship " + shipping.getShippingDate() + " | QTY " + shipping.getQuantity());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i willl get right in to learning how to code it WITH understanding how to do it. I want to learn aswell :)
How do i get the data from the second line of 55401? in the files i get i can have several of the same line 55401 but they all follow the same rules, 55401-DATE-QTY-separator x6

Comment: @Niklas I don't completely get want you want to know. I'd suggest you add a print statement after calling `scan.nextLine()` and print the line. You will then see how all the lines are used.

Comment: Thanks RatzzFatzz, i will try to learn your method, i think i understand how its been made and how it is better, just need to understand how it all works. Im trying to read diffrent calloffs from a customer, the file is diffrent every time but it is still follow a set of rules. For example the first 6 chars after 55401 is always a date etc etc. I understand the code in the file just as easy as you read java, but i need to present the content to ppl that have no understanding of the file at all, like me in java atm :)